# Can I connect a local Parity instance to an instance running on a server?

Tags: parity

Basically, I want to run parity on a server which will keep my blockchain up-to-date at all times.

I also want my employees to be able to run parity (without blockchain) on their local machines with their own accounts, but not have to sync the entire blockchain.

Is there a way to run this heavy-server/light-client configuration of Parity? It is important that each employee maintain their own accounts (Parity instance) but share the blockchain DB.

I would like to avoid having to wait for my local blockchain to update, then wait for someone else to update their blockchain before signing a multisig transaction.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?
I want to do the exact same thing but haven't been able to get it working yet.

Answer (score 1):

> I also want my employees to be able to run parity (without blockchain) on their local machines with their own accounts, but not have to run geth.

Run a [public node](https://paritytech.github.io/wiki/Public-Node.html) on one of your company servers.

```
parity --public node
```

And give your employees access to the UI and RPC. See https://wallet.parity.io/ for an example of such a node.

Their private keys will be stored in their local browser storage, and they can interact with Parity remotely, without having it installed. That makes the importance of backing up the recovery phrase much more important, but achieves your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can able to connect the parity to your server through RPC connection or through IPC connections.
In the parity configuration file (config.toml), you have to change the interface value to your server IP address under WebSockets if you want to connect through RPC else change the path value under IPC to connect through IPC.

For more details regarding configuration of parity [check here.](https://paritytech.github.io/wiki/Configuring-Parity.html)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any direction on how to get multiple remote clients (ETH accounts) to access the same blockchain on a server. The RPC (JSON-RPC & IPC) seems to imply that geth is configured to talk to Parity and not the other way around. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: If you know the ETH address and the password file you can access it anywhere in this world. Your employee can connect to your server and access their accounts since password file was stored on the local machine, for deploying the contract they will use your server machine. In this way, you can avoid syncing blockchain on all your employee's machine

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Right now I have geth running in a docker container on my server exposing port 8545. I want the parity instance running on my computer to talk to server:8545 so my personal computer doesn't have to run geth (maintain blockchain). The `parity --rpcaddr={server_IP} --rpcport=8545` just seems to expose the local geth via that rpc address instead of connecting to my server.

Comment: use the command parity --rpc http://{server_IP:8545} --networkid 123 It will connect the parity client to your server instead of the local instance.